# Check select box has certain options with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

How do I use Capybara to check that a select box has certain values listed as options?
It has to be compatible with Selenium...

This is the HTML that I have:

```
<select id="cars"> 
  <option></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

This is what I want to do:

```
Then the "cars" field should contain the option "audi"
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your HTML/ERB for the section in question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try using the capybara rspec matcher [have_select(locator, options = {})](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara%2FRSpecMatchers%3Ahave_select) instead:

```
#Find a select box by (label) name or id and assert the given text is selected
Then /^"([^"]*)" should be selected for "([^"]*)"$/ do |selected_text, dropdown|
  expect(page).to have_select(dropdown, :selected => selected_text)
end

#Find a select box by (label) name or id and assert the expected option is present
Then /^"([^"]*)" should contain "([^"]*)"$/ do |dropdown, text|
  expect(page).to have_select(dropdown, :options => [text])
end
```

Comment: For the RSpec users out there, I used `page.should have_select('Something', :options => ['plain text'])`

Comment: @hubble your comment should definitely have a response of its own :)

Comment: You can also use `with_options` to check that specific option(s) exist without specifying all in order

Comment: Capybara seems to suggest that `options` is a complete set, whereas `with_options` allows for a subset of the total options, handy for checking that a particular option is in the select without specifying all of the options.  Still looking for something to specify the order. https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb#L372

Comment: Newer RSpec syntax: `expect(page).to have_select(...)`

Comment: Thanks @everyman, I've updated the answer with the new syntax.

Comment: [has_select(locator, options = {})](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_select%3F-instance_method) `page.has_select?('Language', with_options: ['English', 'German'])` if you don't want your test to fail when it isn't not found

Answer (score 22):

For what it's worth, I'd call it a drop-down menu, not a field, so I'd write:

```
Then the "cars" drop-down should contain the option "audi"
```

To answer your question, here's the RSpec code to implement this (untested):

```
Then /^the "([^"]*)" drop-down should contain the option "([^"]*)"$/ do |id, value|
  page.should have_xpath "//select[@id = '#{id}']/option[@value = '#{value}']"
end
```

If you want to test for the option text instead of the value attribute (which might make for [more readable](http://elabs.se/blog/15-you-re-cuking-it-wrong) scenarios), you could write:

```
  page.should have_xpath "//select[@id = '#{id}']/option[text() = '#{value}']"
```

Comment: Options should be option.. ah well, i'm doing it with this page.should have_css('select option:contains('Audi')', :visible => true). Why? Code is more readable, plus checks that the element is visible...

Comment: @Tom: The `contains` pseudo-class was [taken out of the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors), so I'm not sure if this will work everywhere, but other than that, CSS is just as good (and I agree it's more readable).  You can use :visible on [either method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_xpath%3F-instance_method), by the way.  Re learning XPath, I've been getting pretty far with just the [examples in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) (and [these as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths)).

Comment: Oh didn't now that... It's a shame they let go of 'contains()', it looks useful. I'll take a look at the XPath exemples thanks!

Comment: With my rspec/capybara `page.should.have_xpath` does not work, but `page.should have_xpath` does.

Answer (score 16):

As an alternative solution, and as I'm not familiar with xpaths, I did this to solve a similar problem:

```
page.all('select#cars option').map(&:value).should == %w(volvo saab mercedes audi)
```

Its quite simple, but took me some time to figure out.

Answer (score 13):

Well, since i was around and saw the question (and been testing today) decided to post my way:

```
within("select#cars") do
  %w(volvo saab mercedes audi).each do |option|
    expect(find("option[value=#{option}]").text).to eq(option.capitalize)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Then I should see "audi" within "#cars"
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. In cucumber "cars" would be a "field" and "within" implies a scope. So a standard step that comes close is 'Then the "cars" field should contain "Audi"'. But if nothing is selected it returns an empty string: expected: /Audi/,
           got: ""

Comment: how can cars be a field when it's clearly a select tag? you're checking if the option Audi exists in your cars dropdown right? or are you checking if it was the selected option?