# rspec should have_select('cars', :options => ['volvo', 'saab'] not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In home page I have:
 Cars:

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo </option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi </option>
</select>
```

The test code in static_pages_spec.rb:

```
it "should have the right select" do
  visit home_path
  it { should have_select('cars', :options => ['volvo', 'saab','mercedes','audi'])}
end
```

The response is

```
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:21 # Static pages Home page should have the right select
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394799/check-select-box-has-certain-options-with-capybara) most people trying to solve a similar problem would use `#cars` to locate their `select`, but the [capybara docs for `has_select?`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_select?-instance_method) say it will (as usual) find the correct label, name or id. Looking at the examples there I would suggest you try to use the *visible* (capitalized) option names instead of the internal option values.

The third answer in the question I linked to has an example of verifying the internal values (with the exact same options you use which seems a very tough piece of a coincidence :-).

So you could try

```
it { should have_select('#cars', :options => ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi'])}
```

Comment: Thanks you are right the options should be capitalized but the selector is correct without the #
this worked:  `expect(page).to have_select('cars', :options => ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercedes', 'Audi'])`

Comment: You are correct in your statement that this will work, since capybara will find either either name, id or label (as I wrote). However using `#cars` makes it more explicit that you are looking for the id (which I thought you would like to express). As I think your tests should be as expressive as possible I would go for the more specific version *if that is what you would like to express*.